# Efficiently finding the longest substring of repeating characters in a string, with it position

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve this problem with Python implementation, I found many answers about "Finding the longest substring without repeating characters in a string", but in my case, I want to find the substring with repeating characters.

I tried using regex:

```
import sys
import re

s = 'AATTTCCCCGTCAAA'
repeats = r'(.)\1+'

all_repeat = sorted((m.group() for m in re.finditer(repeats, s)),
                    key=len, reverse=True)

substring = [s for s in all_repeat if len(s) == len(all_repeat[0])]
```

It will return all the repeating substring, then search for the longest one. However, this is not efficient, since I only care about the longest one, as well as its position. If I use regex, I will need to search for the string again to find its position, so it will slow down the algorithm more. By position I mean the starting point of the substring.

Any help on this problem is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using `max()` instead of `sorted()`? Maybe also `itertools.groupby()` instead of `re.finditer()`, since that would let you feed an `enumerate(s)` into it, which would preserve the string's index.

Comment: Specifically, I've found that `max((list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(s), key=operator.itemgetter(1))), key=len)` works for getting you the enumerated group with the most consecutive occurrences: `[(5, 'C'), (6, 'C'), (7, 'C'), (8, 'C')]`. You can then extract the character and start of the substring from that.